# How to use the Requests OAuthlib with grant-type 'Client Credentials'?

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, python-requests

So I try to call an API which **only** provides an token url in the docs. For this I want to use the OAuthlib from the python requests package. When I view at [their docs](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/github.html) they give this example:

```py
# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = '<the id you get from github>'
client_secret = '<the secret you get from github>'

# OAuth endpoints given in the GitHub API documentation
authorization_base_url = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize'
token_url = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token'

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
github = OAuth2Session(client_id)

# Redirect user to GitHub for authorization
authorization_url, state = github.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print ('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')

# Fetch the access token
github.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
        authorization_response=redirect_response)

# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
r = github.get('https://api.github.com/user')
print (r.content)
```

But in the API documentation the service only provides the token url. It gives this Http Body `POST` example:

```
Method: POST
Host: https://login.bol.com/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json

Body: client_id=oRNWbHFXtAECmhnZmEndcjLIaSKbRMVE&client_secret= MaQHPOnmYkPZNgeRziPnQyyOJYytUbcFBVJBvbMKoDdpPqaZbaOiLUTWzPAkpPsZFZbJHrcoltdgpZolyNcgvvBaKcmkqFjucFzXhDONTsPAtHHyccQlLUZpkOuywMiOycDWcCySFsgpDiyGnCWCZJkNTtVdPxbSUTWVIFQiUxaPDYDXRQAVVTbSVZArAZkaLDLOoOvPzxSdhnkkJWzlQDkqsXNKfAIgAldrmyfROSyCGMCfvzdQdUQEaYZTPEoA&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Or this HTTP header `POST` example:

```
Method: POST
Host: https://login.bol.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic <credentials>
```

Where `<credentials>` is a concatenation of `<client_id>:<client_secret>` .

How can I use the requests OAuthlib with this API? Because the [API docs](https://developers.bol.com/apiv3authentication/) dont state any authorization base url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can provide `<client_id>:<client_secret>` like this:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://provider.com/oauth2/token', client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret)
```

see [this](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#backend-application-flow)

Answer (score 0):

The link @LinPy provided is good but sometimes you need to configure things like headers and body which that link doesn't help you with.

This is how I found it possible to customise the auth, headers and body.

```py
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient, BackendApplicationClient
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

client_id = CLIENT_ID
client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
authorization_base_url = AUTHORIZE_URI
token_url = TOKEN_URI
redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
scope = SCOPE
header = {
  'User-Agent': 'myapplication/0.0.1',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
}

# Create the Authorization URI
# Not included here but store the state in a safe place for later
the_first_session = OAuth2Session(client_id=client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope)
authorization_url, state = the_first_session.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)

# Browse to the Authorization URI

# Login and Auth with the OAuth provider

# Now to respond to the callback

the_second_session = OAuth2Session(client_id, state=state)

body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=%s' % (request.GET.get('code'), redirect_uri, scope)
token = the_second_session.fetch_token(token_url, code=request.GET.get('code'), auth=auth, header=header, body=body)
```

Comment: Where to request and redirect REDIRECT_URI come from?